# Remove emulateIE7 from jdoc:include type = head in joomla 1.5

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cross-browser, joomla1.5

I was debugging a new part to our site and couldn't figure out why I was getting a weird bug (just some white space issues not a biggie) when I noticed in IE it's telling it to render as ie7, as we're trying to use newer code on the site, such as dabbling in html5, and as less then 5% of our traffic use ie7 I figure its safe to ditch this in favor of ie8/9 compatibility. I also noticed when I swapped the document mode to ie8 the issue I was working on went away.

I'm sure a lot of people can relate to building new content that works fine in everything except IE so I'm hoping outputting as at least the latest version it can will make some of this easier. The problem is the code that forces ie7 is coming from jdoc:include type=head and I don't know how to edit what it pulls through.

Website http://www.webchild.com.au

Code that brings in head

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

Unwanted code that is coming through

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE7">
```

We are running a site off Joomla 1.5 using a heavily modified template which I don't know where the previous dev got from.

Comment: if you are sure that it comes from `<jdoc:include type="head"/>` then it's should be concatenated by some of your currently used template files. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that Joomla usually puts in as part of `<jdoc:include type="head" />` but it, back in the day when this was any kind of a good solution, there were extensions that generated this. If you look in the plugin manager maybe you'll see something to do with "IE8" and/or "compatibility" or "standards." If you find a likely candidate, disable it and see if the X-UA-Compatible header goes away.

If it isn't there, maybe it's an option of the template? From lines like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/yoo_mellow_Nov_2012/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
```

it looks like you're using the 'Mellow" theme from [YouTheme](http://www.yootheme.com/)

Comment: I checked through our plugins but couldn't find a match, I searched through the settings on each one I didn't know what was for and came up with nothing. Is there a way to see what Joomla is pulling through from head? I suppose I Could duplicate the template and remove everything but the <jdoc:include type="head" />

Comment: That or just bracket it with comments like `<!-- include head --><jdoc:include type="head" /><!-- end include head -->`. My next question was going to be, are you sure that's where this header was coming from. Also look under Global Configuration and the Template's configuration to see if isn't just set there as metadata.

Comment: Checked the Global Config and template its not an option, I used your idea with the comments and it is coming from the <jdoc:include type=head />

Comment: Look at `docs/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php` Maybe that's been customized?

Answer (score -1):

If that template were made by professionals, then you should check something like `functions.php` or `someUnusualFile.php` in your template folder. Of course after `index.php`. As far as i know, i would put it into `index.php` but someone could do it in another way.

Show us your html code from `index.php` - only head sections

Comment: As Sean has pointed out for me I believe the template was made by YooTheme and then modified by the numerous people who've worked on the site over the last year or 2. When you compare viewing the source to the index.php file the code I'm looking to get rid of appears above any hard coded links which is why I assumed it was from the
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
as this is the first line in the head

Comment: Also the head part of our template is pretty monstrous, lots of javascript coded into the head and many css files included, though none matches what I'm after.

Comment: I'am doing the same, instead of writing it directly into `index.php`, i create a `functions.php` where my template functions (such as template helpers) are. Also i'am usigin a regex functions to rewrite all buttons to my needs before rendering the page, etc... And there I merge my meta settings into the `jdoc type=head`. This way i can separate a template logic from templating design, by just including one file into `index.php`.